# Python: Beautiful Soup Parsing </li> and <ul> with changing class_= names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't get the green data (

[image: displays the HTML structure]

```
yo = requests.get('http://www.nfl.com/schedules/2019/REG11')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(yo.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('ul', class_="schedules-table")
print(table) #correctly gathers all data and extraneous data
```

Comment: you want to get all green data?

Answer (score 1):

The green data that you see are the comments in html. It can be grabbed using `Comment` class in bs4 -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
yo = requests.get('http://www.nfl.com/schedules/2019/REG11')
soup = BeautifulSoup(yo.text, 'html.parser')
comment = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

Will get you all the comments on the page. You will have to filter out relevant comments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The things highlighted in green are **comments**. You can grab them using this code:

```
from bs4 import Comment
comments = table.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

It will put them all in a list. Up to you to code them into a dataframe or something else that you want.